# Laravel Eloquent Updates Every Row Values Mistakenly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

My purpose :
1. get the id of the row from user input,
2. change the first row of selected row's values.

I have a model like this :

**myModel.php**

```
class myModel extends Eloquent{
   protected $table = 'myTable';
   protected $primaryKey = 'id';
   public $timestamps = false;
   public incrementing = false;
   protected fillable = array(
      'id', //yes it needs to be fillable...
      'name',
      'surname'
   );
}
```

**myController.php**

```
class myController extends BaseController{
   public function someFunction(){
      $modelInstance = myModel::where('id', Session::get('id'))
         ->where('otherID', Input::get('someHTMLInput'))
         ->first();

      $modelInstance->id = Session::get('id');
      $modelInstance->name = Input::get('someNameInput');
      $modelInstance->surname = Input::get('someSurnameInput');

      $modelInstance->save();
   }
}
```

**Here's what happens** :
1. I can post values that i get from inputs nicely
2. when it comes to the controller's save method, query updates every rows' values including that following ID number.
i.e. on the database

```
id=1; otherID=1; name=aaa; surname=bbb;
id=1; otherID=2; name=xxx; surname=yyy;
id=1; otherID=3; name=ccc; surname=ddd;
```

When i try to change name aaa->rrr that happens:

```
id=1; otherID=1; name=rrr; surname=bbb;
id=1; otherID=2; name=rrr; surname=yyy;
id=1; otherID=3; name=rrr; surname=ddd;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Eloquent doesn't currently support composite primary keys](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355)

Comment: @lukasgeiter any way to do this with using syntax like myModal::updateOrCreate(['']); ? But it still seems like eloquent.

Comment: No that won't work. It uses `save()` which will only use one primary key field... I'll answer in a second with what you could do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent doesn't currently support composite primary keys. There's a discussion going on [over at github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355) if you want to show your support for the issue.

---

What you can do, is this:

```
myModel::where('id', Session::get('id'))
    ->where('otherID', Input::get('someHTMLInput'))
    ->update([
        'name' => Input::get('someNameInput'),
        'surname' => Input::get('someSurnameInput')
    ]);
```

However, with this you use pretty much all model functionality. It's basically the same as:

```
DB::table('my_model')->where('id', Session::get('id'))
    ->where('otherID', Input::get('someHTMLInput'))
    ->update([
        'name' => Input::get('someNameInput'),
        'surname' => Input::get('someSurnameInput')
    ]);
```

Comment: I will test it out and let you know the results. Thank you so much.

Comment: thank you so much. It solved my problem and also i see that eloquent doesn't currently support composite primary keys. I will visit the github page too though.

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is the primary key, set it in database as primary, and autoincrement if needed. here in this code all ids are 1 so it updates all rows. You can set `protected $primaryKey = 'id';` to `protected $primaryKey = 'otherId';` , if you need to update data corresponding to otherId.